# Interactive actions in notification view not visible on iOS 10 ( xcode 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to implement Notification Framework and does anyone know why  I am not getting two action buttons in interactive notification? When I swipe to the left I only have 'Clear' button visible

Thanks in advance

```
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if( !error )
         {

             NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
             // create actions
             UNNotificationAction *ackAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"com.elonchan.yes"
                                                                                       title:@"Acknowledge"
                                                                                     options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
             UNNotificationAction *detailsAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"com.elonchan.no"
                                                                                        title:@"Details"
                                                                                      options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
             NSArray *notificationActions = @[ ackAction, detailsAction ];

             // create a category
             UNNotificationCategory *inviteCategory = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"com.elonchan.localNotification"
                                                                                             actions:notificationActions

                                                                                      intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                                                                             options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
             NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:inviteCategory];

             // registration
             [center setNotificationCategories:categories];
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications

             NSLog( @"Push rsetNotificationCategories success." );
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
             NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
             NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 10 your actions show up when a user force-touches your notification. Give that a shot and you should see your actions.

Comment: Patrick, thanks! You were right. Sorry for the late acceptance of answer, even I saw your answer day after...